# adress mapping of PCI -device in Linux-Kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, pci

I tried to connect my PCI device to embedded Android. Unfortunately, I can't use command "lspci" . After `dmesg | grep pci` I  see :

```
 pci 0001:00:00.0: [17cb:0104] type 01 class 0x060400
 msm_pcie_oper_conf: Read of RC1 0:0x00 + 0x0014[4] is all FFs
 pci 0001:00:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff 64bit]
 pci 0001:00:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
 pci 0001:00:00.0: of_irq_parse_pci() failed with rc=-19
 pci 0001:00:00.0: bridge configuration invalid ([bus 00-00]), reconfiguring
 pci 0001:01:00.0: [126f:0750] type 00 class 0x030000
 pci 0001:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0x00000000-0x03ffffff pref]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: reg 0x14: [mem 0x00000000-0x001fffff]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: reg 0x30: [mem 0x00000000-0x0000ffff pref]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: supports D1
 pci 0001:01:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D1 D3hot
 pci_bus 0001:01: busn_res: [bus 01-ff] end is updated to 01
 msm_pcie_oper_conf: Read of RC1 0:0x00 + 0x0028[4] is all FFs
 pci 0001:00:00.0: BAR 8: no space for [mem size 0x06000000]
 pci 0001:00:00.0: BAR 8: failed to assign [mem size 0x06000000]
 pci 0001:00:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0x0d300000-0x0d300fff 64bit]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 0: no space for [mem size 0x04000000 pref]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 0: failed to assign [mem size 0x04000000 pref]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 1: no space for [mem size 0x00200000]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 1: failed to assign [mem size 0x00200000]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 6: no space for [mem size 0x00010000 pref]
 pci 0001:01:00.0: BAR 6: failed to assign [mem size 0x00010000 pref]
 pci 0001:00:00.0: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
```

When I tried to load kernel module (driver for pci-device) device with Android crashed. Reason of crash is attempt of reading pointer (mem + some_offset). 
How can I fix this troubles?

Thanks and regards

Comment: This sounds like a bug in that driver (it doesn't check that the resource is valid).

Comment: Is it FPGA? You have to choose address ranges carefully, and you need to support PCI specification.

Comment: Well, the dmesg messages indicate some failure to allocate i/o space for a BAR, and the sizes are 0x06000000, 0x04000000...  and earlier there's a bridge reconfiguration.

Comment: Where I can fix it? If I understand in a correct way  information  about BAR and mmaping will locate in device tree.